# What does a lattice of the direct power of the two-element chain look like?

Tags: intuition, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

In universal algebra, it is known that every finite Boolean lattice is isomorphic to a direct power of the two-element chain.

I am having hard time figuring out what a lattice of the direct power of the two-element chain looks like.

For example, let X={1, 2, 3}. What does a lattice of $2^X$ look like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Part of [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107086/visualizing-lattice-products)  asks:

Is there is an easy way to visually understand the Lattice product, as defined by:

$$
L_1 \times L_2\times\ ...\times\ L_n = \{(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)\ \vert \ x_i \in L_i\}
$$

Whether this is easy depends on the lattices $L_i$ and the number $n$, but when the lattices are chains and $n\leq 3$, as in your case, the answer is yes, the product is easy to visualize.

In [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107086/visualizing-lattice-products/109777#109777) to the question mentioned above, there is a Hasse diagram showing the $2 \times 2 \times 3$ lattice and the $2 \times 3 \times 3$ lattice.  The lattice you are asking about, $2\times 2 \times 2$, is a sublattice of each of those diagrams -- it consists of just one cube.